# Linking WSAAsyncSelect with Mingw - undefined reference

Tags: winapi, mingw

I am porting a voip application I wrote in Borland to Mingw so I know the code works.  I use the command line `gcc -lws2_32 -mwindows voipapp.c -o voipapp` and keep getting the error message

> undefined reference to 'WSAAsyncSelect@16'".

It appears to be properly locating `libws2_32.a` since no error messages come up telling me otherwise.  Any ideas as to what can be wrong?  I have one of the most recent versions of mingw installed.  Thanks!

My code is as follows:

```c
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#define __MT__
#include <mmreg.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <process.h>

#define WM_SOCKETREAD (WM_USER + 1)

SOCKET ListenSocket;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
           LPSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow) {

    static char szAppName[] = "voip";
    HWND        hwnd;
    MSG         msg;
    WNDCLASSEX  wndclass;

    wndclass.cbSize         = sizeof(wndclass);
    wndclass.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wndclass.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wndclass.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wndclass.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wndclass.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wndclass.hIcon          = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndclass.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndclass.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndclass.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wndclass.lpszClassName  = szAppName;
    wndclass.lpszMenuName   = NULL;

    RegisterClassEx(&wndclass);

    hwnd = CreateWindow(szAppName, "VOIP prototype",
            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
            CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
            NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    ShowWindow(hwnd, iCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);


    WSAAsyncSelect(ListenSocket, hwnd, WM_SOCKETREAD, FD_READ|FD_CLOSE);


    while ( GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) ) {
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg); 
        } 

    return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT iMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, iMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must specify correct linking order.

Try:

```
gcc voipapp.c -o voipapp -mwindows -lws2_32
```